# CountDown Timer in js sync with server

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a auction platform and I want to display a count down timer precisely in seconds, server will return the auction closing date.

When I ping a server to get auction closing time, this request may take some time to process, thus making countdown timer unreliable.

Since I can't relay on client side clock, how can I make it work perfectly?

Comment: "I can't rely on client side clock" - why not? If you can't do that, you can't.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I can't rely on client clock because client clock can be few minutes faster or slower? since client might have set time manually.

Comment: If the client set the time manually, a wrong timer should be expected bahavior for the user. I don't see a problem.

Comment: true, but I don't want to show wrong countdown timer, moreover client time might be wrong for many reasons that he might even itself didn't know of that, in that case I can't show wrong timer.

Comment: You can synchronize the client clock to the server clock in case it has the wrong time (not as in changing the client's system time), however your goal will be very hard if not impossible to achieve if you cannot rely on the client's clock behaving properly even over a short period of time. If you wouldn't care about a minor time difference, you could just send the remaining time instead of the end of the auction, subtract the minimum estimated network delay and computation time and probably be accurate within a fraction of a second if the server doesn't lag.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the server time every minute, get the remaining hour and minute, then on the client, countdown the seconds left in each minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a websocket, it's perfect for real time applications:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/